# Maximizing a trigonometric function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, trigonometry

This is probably a naive question, but here it goes:

I know that 
$$r\cos a+s\cos b+t\cos c \leq \frac{rs}{2t}+\frac{rt}{2s}+\frac{ts}{2r},$$

subject to the conditions $a+b+c=\pi$ and $r,s,t$ are positive reals.

My question is whether I can ask Mathematica to find the RHS in the above inequality.

I tried:

```
Maximize[{r*Cos[a] + s*Cos[b] + t*Cos[c], c = Pi - a - b, r > 0, s > 0, t > 0}, {a, b}]
```

Comment: Please write down the Mathematica code you tried. Thanks!

Comment: Maximize[{r*cos[a] + s*cos[b] + t*cos[c], c = pi - a - b, r > 0, 
  s > 0, t > 0}, {a, b}]

Comment: You got syntax issues - take care of upper/lowercase spelling, and `=` is not equivalent to `==`.

Comment: Maximize[{r*Cos[a] + s*Cos[b] + t*Cos[Pi - a - b], r > 0, s > 0, 
  t > 0}, {a, b}] ?

Comment: Yes, that's now capitalized correctly.

Comment: Ok, Mathematica does not return anything though. I guess it can't do it?

Comment: By the way, I have had a similar problem in the past. A human would go about proving such an inequality in the usual way, i.e. by checking for local maxima on the boundary of the region and in the interior and applying standard results from Calculus. Can't Mathematica carry out a similar procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way of obtaining the result that you want.

Define the expression to be maximised, using `a + b + c == Pi` to eliminate `c`.

```
expr = r Cos[a] + s Cos[b] + t Cos[Pi - a - b];
```

Solve for the stationary points w.r.t. `a` and `b`.

```
sol = Solve[D[expr, a] == 0 && D[expr, b] == 0, {a, b}]

(* Lots of ConditionalExpression due to the periodicity of the expression being maximised *)
```

Substitute the solutions back into the expression. Then post-process the result in several stages: (1) `FullSimplify` using that `{r, s, t} > 0`, (2) `Refine` to remove the degeneracy due to periodicity, and (3) `Expand` to write the results nicely.

```
expr0 = expr /. sol //
  FullSimplify[#, {r, s, t} > 0] & //
  Refine[#, C[1] \[Element] Integers && C[2] \[Element] Integers] & //
  Expand

(*
  {
    r + s - t,
    r - s + t,
    -r + s + t,
    -r - s - t,
    (r s)/(2 t) + (r t)/(2 s) + (s t)/(2 r),
    (r s)/(2 t) + (r t)/(2 s) + (s t)/(2 r)
  }
*)
```

Check all of these stationary values against the conjectured upper bound.

```
ForAll[{r, s, t}, {r, s, t} > 0, 
  expr0 <= (r s)/(2 t) + (r t)/(2 s) + (s t)/(2 r)] // Resolve

(* True *)
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want get the same symbolic result, i'm afraid mathematica cant handle that. But still a few comments. The first is of course syntax problems (see example below). You can always consider numerical task: say, you want to maximize left side with known right side, i.e. known r,s,t. Another point - Maximize cant manage all the tasks for sure, consider using NMaximize. I would suggest:

```
r = 1;
t = 2;
s = 3;
NMaximize[{r Cos[a] + s Cos[b] + t Cos[c], a + b + c == Pi}, {a, b, c}]
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am not interested in numerical solutions though; rather, I was hoping for an "inequality proving" routine within Mathematica.